# Reactive (rxjava) question on Maybe<List> vs Flowable etc

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm still learning some of the specifics of reactive/rxjava, and had a quick question on a use case I come across commonly.

We often have services that grab entries from a DB or some other data source, and return it to other services or a client via an HTTP controller. My question is something along these lines: is there any practical difference between exposing this data as a `Flowable<DTO>` versus a `Maybe<List<DTO>>` (or `Single<List<DTO>>` when appropriate). All the data will have been loaded at once from the data source, so it will be in a List locally.

I assume if there were a use case where a DB call returned a large number of values, exposing them via a Flowable could be a better option so that the caller can deal with them at its own pace? But if it's just a small number of records I imagine it's negligible. Or, similarly, is there a case where returning the `Maybe<List<DTO>>` would be preferable?

Am I misunderstanding anything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you say, this really depends on your use case, how many `DTO`s you handle, and how they are packaged.

If you have a `Flowable<DTO>` in the most general case, then you can apply backpressure by only accepting what you can handle right now. Also, you can construct observer chains that convert the result to a list:

```
Flowable<DTO> source;

// capture all the data:
source.
  toList().
  subscribe( /* Handle a List<DTO> */);
// Some data in a bunch
source.
  buffer(20).
  subscribe( /* Handle a List<DTO>, 20 entries at a time */ );
```

The major point is that RxJava allows you to compose your chains of observers into the types of results you find most convenient to deal with. The RxJava model allows you to cross time and space boundaries readily.

Comment: Great, thank you for the input! I think that confirms mostly what I thought was the case. Is it safe to summarize that for small sets of data, the difference is mostly just stylistic, but that for larger sets a Flowable allows for finer tuned performance?

Comment: In broad, the `Flowable` allows creating computation chains that span time and space. For small data sets, you likely don't need that control, or you can use traditional data structures. Once you need results in more than one place, or on multiple threads, or in multiple different formats, or at multiple different times, then `Flowable` becomes a clear win.